# Using bash curl to get access token to a google Apps api

Tags: api, curl, google-apps, google-oauth

I am seeking for a simple tutorial using bash curl and json files to get an access token to a google api.

Something like this

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d @JSONFILE <url>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your existing curl command?

Comment: What I am missing is the process of doing it with google.

Comment: I created the clientid using console.developers.google.com but what to do next? the google tutorials are all based on a language. What I need is to use them directly with curl.

Comment: For example: How to create a bash script to get the list of users of a "google apps domain"

Comment: For list of users it should be: `curl https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`